# Sort by selection..spreadsheet software

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, gis

I am so frustrated... I use ArcMap a lot and therefore I use the 'show selected features' a lot when I am in the attribute table.  Now I need to manipulate a csv file in excel with 150,000+ records and I absolutely have to do the same thing....I use the Find tool to select a few hundred rows at a time, then I need to show only those selected and then populate an empty field with values for only those rows.

This cannot be done in any spreadsheet package as far as I am concerned.  I scoured excel and openoffice for the solution but there is none.  The records have too many special characters to bring into ArcMap or else I would just do it with Esri.

Any ideas?  This seems so crazy to me...such a fundamental thing that is not available....

Comment: Welcome to GIS-SE!  However, this question seems to be purely about how to "sort by selection [in] spreadsheet software".  Although it mentions ArcMap the question is not about ArcMap.  Consequently, I think it would be better migrated to [**Stack Overflow**](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? When you say "I use the Find tool to select a few hundred rows at a time" are you talking about in Excel or ArcMap. Can you [edit] the question to only include what you are asking about Excel? The talk of other programs is making your question confusing.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser,  @CharlieRB makes an excellent point, since you've been migrated to SuperUser, the question probably should be recrafted to more specifically address your program concerns.  It's also a bit vague, so anything you can do to help clarify what you're looking for will be helpful.  As it is, it runs the risk of being closed for being vague or not constructive.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a database solution.  Excel, versatile as it is, is still just a spreadsheet.  If you use SQL (MS has a free version of SQL, more info here: [SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/database.aspx), making a massive number of changes is extremely easy.  Your workflow would be something like this:

1. Import your .csv data into a Database Table.
2. Manipulate your data, perhaps a TSQL statement like:

   > Update YOUR_CSV_TABLE (your source data)
   >
   > Set Column 2 = NewValue (specify any number of columns to be updated, with your new value)
   >
   > Where Column 1 = Criteria (match whatever value(s) you need

   This type of SQL statement can update thousands of rows simulataneously.
3. Connect your SQL database to  ArcMap as a data source.

I use a similar setup on a pretty regular basis and it works great.

Comment: Thanks to whoever for migrating, I am very new here so I wasn't sure where to post my question. David - thanks, this looks promising, I will be uploading my csv to mysql and will have phpmyadmin so I will try your solution from there.  I just couldn't believe this method is not doable in excel/openoffice. Thanks for the help, people.